# Rebinding/disabling CTRL+ALT+F# Virtual Terminal/Console Switching

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, tty, console, virtual-consoles

I have an application that binds <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but my linux machine seems to catch the keystroke.

Is there a way to rebind/disable this key? A recompile of the kernel is an acceptable answer.

The distributions in question are Fedora 16 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I don't have any specific advice, but I think, as CTRL+ALT+Fn is bound only under the X-Windows System, that the kernel won't be related to it in any way, and that you will probably be luckier trying to tweak the X11 configuration.

Comment: @njsg You can use the same keys to switch from X11 to a vt, and to switch back (also between vt's) - so they must be bound just the same on a vt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place this in your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file to disable VT switching with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
EndSection
```

You will also need the following to cause events to be passed through to clients connected to the display:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XKbOptions" "srvrkeys:none"
EndSection
```

(That last bit is untested, refer to [its source](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1779702.html).)

Comment: This does not forward the combination to the window, X still catches it.

Comment: I did some Googling and found you need to add something else to the config file. Let me know if it works.

Comment: After a few months of having to run Windows I have finally tested this on Lubuntu 12.04, where the IntelliJ IDEA window still does not catch the keystroke.

Comment: Using the two settings was both required for me, and worked for me. (on centos). ctrl-alt-f7 is now showing the usages inline in intellij :).

Comment: If you are using Intellij and want to use `CTL+ALT+F7` for "Show usage", on Lubuntu 15.04, the default shortcut is acutally `CTL+ALT+7`. You would need to change it back to `CTL+ALT+F7` if you want to keep consistent with other OSes.

Comment: Just to confirm this works on FreeBSD 11 too.

Comment: @XiaoPeng You can switch the entire keymap to 'Default' and then you'll get all the old shortcuts.

Comment: How about for Wayland? How would you disable it there?

Comment: I think it would be up to individual compositors (e.g., weston, gnome-shell, plasma) to provide a mechanism to disable VT switching.

Answer (score 29):

The following invocation of the X11 `setxkbmap` command disables Ctrl-Alt-Fn console/virtual terminal switching:

```
setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none
```

To return to the previous behavior of the ctrl-alt-Fn keys, and also remove all other options, such as `caps:ctrl_modifier`:

```
setxkbmap -option ''
```

To print the current settings invoke `setxkbmap -print`.

To invoke per user, put the command in the ~/.xinitrc file.

To invoke when an Xsession starts, create a file in

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d
```

such as

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/65srvrkeys-none
```

containing the above `setxkbmap` command, and make it executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/X11/Xsession.d/65srvrkeys-none`.

For more information type `man setxkbmap` at your shell prompt or see the [Xorg setxkbmap man page](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml).

I tested this with KDE on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty). These settings are also available in System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced.  If you change `srvrkeys` in the GUI Settings, it shows up immediately in `setxkbmap` and vice versa.

I prefer to modify the X window system via the X11 command line interfaces.  If that does not work, then I attempt the desktop environment.  As a last resort I would modify system configuration files.  Implementations and file formats change, but command line interfaces live almost forever in the Unix/Linux tradition.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertL. My hopes were high, but no, this doesn't seem to have any effect on my Debian jessie and Ubuntu 14.04 installations. Ctrl-Alt-F7 and Ctrl-Alt-F8 still switch back and forth to and from a virtual terminal. I also don't have that menu entry System Settings > Input Devices > ... Perhaps that's a KDE thing? I'm using GNOME or whatever the Ubuntu default is.

Comment: I have tried several ways and this one was the only that works in Lubuntu 16.04, it works when I'm logged in. Do you know how to get it to work in lxdm's greeter screen? (in ubuntu with lightdm works).

Comment: It works on Linux Mint 18. Thank you.

Comment: It works for me on Debian 8 (Jessie).   NOTE: I only tested the command line `setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none`.  I put the entry in a file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/65srvrkeys-none`.  And while I haven't logged out and back in yet, I presume it will work just fine.

Comment: Works like a charm on Linux 18.3, many thanks.

Comment: Works in Kubuntu 1804, cheers.

Comment: Why would I want to restart X, per @Sam Morris's accepted answer, when I could stop it from stealing the keypress from my vmware vSphere 6.5 web console with one simple, instant, easily undone command?  RobertL, you sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  All the ghits saying Ctrl-Alt-Space, release Space, F1, that no longer works with webconsole.  All the ones saying "host key", I don't know what that refers to.  All the ones referring to VMRC, I don't have a my.vmware.com account to download that from.

Comment: Worked fine for me on Debian Buster; like @MikeyE I haven't logged out yet (and will probably not do so in a couple of weeks/months ;-) but the `setxkbmap` approach did the trick. Much appreciated!

Comment: I only tested the disabling so far and it works great, thanks for proper Linux-style solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable this by going to System settings -> keyboard layout -> option.
under miscellaneous compatibility options check "special keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><key></kbd> handled in server".

I checked this and Ubuntu does not catch any combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+... .
but still idea does not catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and the problem still exits!!!.

Comment: You are right Ubuntu does not catch it, but I suspect that the X server does.

Comment: Yay! Found out that by default in Ubuntu IDEA handles Ctrl + Alt + **7** instead of **F7**!

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04 you need to create the following file:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/65-setxkbmap
```

with this content:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XKbOptions" "srvrkeys:none"
EndSection
```

then reboot your system.

Comment: Except for the filename, this has been suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Gnome Wayland: You can unset the keybindings for virtual terminal switching by setting these dconf properties:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-10 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-11 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-12 "['']"
```