# How to send all keystrokes to a screen session?

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

I am starting a screen session with `screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200`. The system I am opening a session to is running Ubuntu, and I would like to pass it Ctrl-Alt-F1. How can I make screen capture those keystrokes and send it to the system?

Answer (score 1):

`screen` does not know anything about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.  It only knows about sequences of bytes.  The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> *may* have meaning to a terminal emulator in which you are running `screen` (and send an interesting sequence of bytes to the application), but its meaning may be (as in a Linux virtual console) be built-in in a manner which prevents the key from sending data to your application.

For instance, the [Linux Keyboard and Console HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-8.html) says that this combination will switch to virtual terminal number 1.

According to [How to disable Ctrl + Alt + Function key combinations on Debian?](https://superuser.com/questions/302460/how-to-disable-ctrl-alt-function-key-combinations-on-debian), you can *disable* the switching while running in X, while [How to disable “ctrl + alt + Fn” shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125164/how-to-disable-ctrl-alt-fn-shortcut) gives similar advice while cautioning that doing this will disable other useful features.

Finally, [Rebinding/disabling CTRL+ALT+F#](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34158/rebinding-disabling-ctrlaltf) gives more examples.

None of those give any clue regarding what *bytes* might be received by an application once the configuration is changed, though the referenced comments in [DontVTSwitch doesn't pass through Ctrl-Alt-(Shift)-Fn to applications](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1779702.html) claims that it works.