# How can I disable F1 key in linux console (i.e. to prevent tty switching)?

Tags: tty, screen-lock

pressing `CTRL-ALT-F1` allows to switch to tty1.
Being on another tty. I can change the keymap using `loadkeys FILE`.

What would be a way to disable F1 key?
Would that allow to prevent switching to the tty1?

Answer (score 2):

With `dumpkeys -s |grep Console` you get a list of all the available characters, and glyphs, and functions containing "Console".

There is switch-to-1 to switch-to-63, plus Incr/Decr and Last_Console.

Here is how I defined them in a keymap file.

```
]# grep Cons dkm.map
keycode  59 = Console_1  F1
keycode  60 = Console_2  F2 
...
keycode  67 = Console_9  F9
keycode  68 = Console_10 F10
keycode  87 = Console_11 F11 
keycode  88 = Console_12 F12
keycode 125 = Last_Console nul Incr_Console nul Decr_Console 
keycode 127 = Incr_Console Decr_Console
```

Instead of Alt-F1 and **Arrows left and right** I have F1 and the "Windows" keys. After `loadkeys dkm.map` this is active.

To just prevent all switching you can comment / delete all the lines containing "Console" in your keyboard map file.

`man keymaps` (keyboard table descriptions for loadkeys and dumpkeys) is a good man page for that (not a command).

Then there is still `chvt tty1` command for switching...

Answer (score 1):

You would better disable the ability to do this directly on X.Org.

See this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34158/rebinding-disabling-ctrlaltf-virtual-terminal-console-switching) for that.

In short, add

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
EndSection
```

Into your `/etc/X11/Xorg.conf`

**ANSWER EDITED SINCE I MISUNDERSTOOD OP REQUEST**

disclaimer: i never used wayland ... This proposition is mainly based on the assumption that `wayland` run or may run in foreground.

So if i understand well, you have a wayland session you can't lock and you want to switch to linux console and lock it so that one can't take the hand on your wayland session.

What i would do is:

1. Login on the linux console (lets say `/dev/tty1`).
2. Launch `wayland` from this console.

At this point, ̀ wayland` is running on foreground on tty1.
Then when i want to lock the session:

1. Switch back to the linux console (tty1).
2. Interrupt `wayland` using your shell job control (`ctrl-z`).
3. Launch `screen` utility and use it to lock console (`ctrl-a x`).

When you want to continue:
1. Unlock screen with your system password.
2. Resume `wayland` with `fg` builtin.

Using this "workaround", even if one can switch to `wayland`, it won't response since you put interrupt it with `ctrl-z`.

Comment: I came accross the question/answer you mention also. However my use-case is that I have a wayland session (without any GDM/LightDM). Lacking a way to lock the screen in wayland I want to switch to a tty and lock the screen there. So I need to disable tty switching. If I used Xorg this might be a way to achieve this. In theory I could start a screenlocking Xorg server, but I think this would be overkill if a locked tty console would do.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i misunderstood your initial request. I will edit my answer with another workaround.

Comment: Thank you. Also I am sorry that I have not been clearer

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting your question literally, what you are looking for is [xmodmap.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap)  You can use `xev -event keyboard` to find the keycode value.  You can then use xmodmap to disable it.

Here are a couple of relevant SuperUser posts:

https://superuser.com/questions/775785/how-to-disable-a-keyboard-key-in-linux-ubuntu

https://superuser.com/questions/1296401/xmodmap-how-to-remap-keys-and-disable-the-original-ones/1299426